# Program type already present: android.support.annotation.AnimRes

Tags: android, xamarin, android-support-library

This problem happened to me after i updated to the latest version of Xamarin.Forms (4.6.0)
I get this error whenever i try to build my Android Projects in Visual Studio For Mac (8.5.4)
What i tried so far:

- Using different versions of the Android Support libraries
- Cleaning my NuGet Cache
- Reinstalling the SDK
- Cleaning, Rebuilding, Restarting VS (several times)

Oddly i managed to get it working for a few builds after changing my support library versions from 28.0.0.3 to 28.0.0.1 manually in the csproj file. However i tried this several times and it doesn't solve the problem. 
The problem occurs if i create a fresh Xamarin.Forms project aswell.

Any advice appreciated, as this is starting to be frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will help, but you should migrate to AndroidX as soon as possible, nevertheless. Xamarin has [migrated to them](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin-essentials-go-androidx/), starting from Forms 4.5

Here is some more information about the libraries - [Introducing AndroidX for Xamarin](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/androidx-for-xamarin/)

There is a special NuGet package for the migration - [Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration). Also available is a built-in functionality in Visual Studio - [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/androidx-nuget-packages-are-stable/)

What I can suggest is you try to migrate to AndroidX libraries, since the old support libraries won't be supported from now on, and you will surely encounter some issues if not like this one, then something else will pop-up in the future.

Comment: I don't know why they don't make it clear somehow that you sohuld do that, but thank you a lot it worked in my case!